# How to open multiple instances of an Electron app

Tags: electron

It seems like everybody is focused on keeping only one instance, but I'm trying to open new instances of my electron app.

I'm using the following but it always opens on the same instance:

```
 electron.shell.openExternal('my-protocol://home')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electron is based on Chromium which is not designed to work with multiple instances using the same `userData` directory at the same time. Things like `localStorage`, IndexedDb, etc, don't work or fail.

You can open multiple windows to give the impression of multiple instances of your app but you should only use one main process.

Comment: But how VSCode is managing this? Also in the browser, you may have multiple tabs of the same website which will use the same localStorage, IndexedDb etc., why this is problem for Electron?

Comment: With Electron, you can only have one Electron main process per `userData` directory. However, as I mentioned above, there's nothing stopping you from having dozens of renderers/windows opened and controlled from a single main process. This is how multiple tabs work in Chrome...